# How can i bind to fields if i can't create properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I'm trying to programmicaly bind fields to controls, i'm generating whem like this:

```
private void GenerateForm<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        InputGrid.Children.Clear();
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var property in type.GetFields(Flags))
        {
            InputGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(AutoSizeRowDefinition);
            var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text = property.Name, Margin = _margin };
            Grid.SetRow(textBlock, i++);
            InputGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);

            InputGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(AutoSizeRowDefinition);
            var control = GetControl(property);
            Grid.SetRow(control, i++);
            InputGrid.Children.Add(control);
        }

        InputGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(AutoSizeRowDefinition);
        var button = new Button { Content = "Отправить", Margin = _margin, MinHeight = 60};
        button.Click += GetButtonClick<T>();
        Grid.SetRow(button, i);
        InputGrid.Children.Add(button);
    }
```

so i can't create properties because it's "Add reference" auto-generated classes that generate fields, not properties

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18058")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/")]
public partial class appointmentReceptionToDoctor : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

private string doctorSpecialityCodeField;

private string doctorSpecialityField;

... and so on
```

So how should I bind them for all this stuff works? Probably generate classes in runtime with properties named like fields and after convert them back, but it seems to complex.

**Added:** Some classes was generated properly with properties, and some classes was generated with public fields. I dunno why. I'm trying to remap them but now remote is unavailable.

I'm adding like this:[image]

And i get classes like this

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getLpusInfo", WrapperNamespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getLpusInfo {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string omsNumber;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string omsSeries;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public System.DateTime birthDate;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=3)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string lpuTypeCode;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=4)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string lpuName;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=5)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string baseLpuAddress;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=6)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public Lanit.Emias.RemoteServices.Appointment.PGUServicesInfo.serviceLpuAddress serviceLpuAddress;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/", Order=7)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string externalSystemId;

    public getLpusInfo() {
    }

    public getLpusInfo(string omsNumber, string omsSeries, System.DateTime birthDate, string lpuTypeCode, string lpuName, string baseLpuAddress, Lanit.Emias.RemoteServices.Appointment.PGUServicesInfo.serviceLpuAddress serviceLpuAddress, string externalSystemId) {
        this.omsNumber = omsNumber;
        this.omsSeries = omsSeries;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.lpuTypeCode = lpuTypeCode;
        this.lpuName = lpuName;
        this.baseLpuAddress = baseLpuAddress;
        this.serviceLpuAddress = serviceLpuAddress;
        this.externalSystemId = externalSystemId;
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18058")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.service.soap.emias.lanit.ru/")]
public partial class serviceLpuAddress : baseDto {

    private string areaField;

    private string districtField;

    private string streetField;

    private string houseField;

    private string buildingField;

    private string constructionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string area {
        get {
            return this.areaField;
        }
        set {
            this.areaField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("area");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string district {
        get {
            return this.districtField;
        }
        set {
            this.districtField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("district");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
    public string street {
        get {
            return this.streetField;
        }
        set {
            this.streetField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("street");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
    public string house {
        get {
            return this.houseField;
        }
        set {
            this.houseField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("house");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
    public string building {
        get {
            return this.buildingField;
        }
        set {
            this.buildingField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("building");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=5)]
    public string construction {
        get {
            return this.constructionField;
        }
        set {
            this.constructionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("construction");
        }
    }
}
```

i dunno why they differ :(

Comment: With your edit, just go with whatever created the second set of output ("or like this:") - that should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, explain it, my english doesn't allow me to understand your response... Anyway in my case i must work with "incorrect" files and "correct" left for another developer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* there aren't properties for that? Because private fields won't be very usable; web-references (whether wsdl-based or svcutil-based) usually add properties.

However, if it genuinely doesn't, then since it is a `partial class`: *you still can*: in a second code file, in the correct namespace:

```
namespace Get.This.Right
{
    partial class appointmentReceptionToDoctor {
        public string DoctorSpecialityCode {
            get { return doctorSpecialityCodeField; }
            set { doctorSpecialityCodeField = value; }
        }

        // etc
    }
}
```

Frankly, however, I find it very peculiar that the generated type *doesn't* have properties and only has private fields - it would be virtually unusable. And indeed, `INotifyPropertyChanged` (which it implements) seems rather pointless if it doesn't already have properties. Are you sure there isn't already a `DoctorSpeciality` and `DoctorSpecialityCode` in the generated code?

Comment: I have **many** classes and it should be too hard to make wrappers for each manualy

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky I'm still confused why there aren't already properties. The standard tools will generate properties by default. What tool are you using the generate the files?

Comment: Standart. VS2012. RightClick->AddReference

Comment: @Alex Well, "Add Reference" adds *assembly* references. Do you mean "Add Web Reference"?

Comment: See above, please, added some info.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to address this problem is to either create a 'wrapper' class to wrap your generated class in, or to just create a normal class with the same properties *plus* your extra required properties in. Then you just need to iterate through any collections that you may have and copy the values from your generated class instances into your new class instances.